# Perl: Writing "if a whole loop finishes successfully then do something"

Tags: perl

I want to write the following logic. If a whole loop is succesfull (that is, if every element of the array that is the object of the loop is transformed), then a database operation (a commit) should follow.

I wrote the following:

```
    if ($room->save ){ # this line i cant modify
　　　　for ( @{ $room->members } ) {
　　　　　if ( $_->save ){      
　　　　　　　$room->ds->commit;                                                                                                                           
　　　　　} else {              
　　　　　return $c->render_ng_json("fail");
 　  　　}                     
　　 }
```

My problem is that in my code, each time $_->save is successful, the database operation will be applied, which is too expensive. If there are 12 members and each one is succesfully saved, there will be 12 attempts to commit. i want perl to analyze if the whole loop had no errors (that is, if every member was saved), and only in that case, do a commit. How to write this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
if ($room->save ){ # this line i cant modify
    for ( @{ $room->members } ) {
        return $c->render_ng_json("fail") unless $_->save ;
    }
    $room->ds->commit;                                                                                                                           
}
```

If you want to do partial commit:

```
if ($room->save ){ # this line i cant modify
    my $failed = 0;
    for ( @{ $room->members } ) {
        $failed = 1 unless $_->save ;
    }
    $room->ds->commit;                                                                                                                           
    return $c->render_ng_json("fail") if $failed ;
}
```

Comment: Careful, this isn't _quite_ the same. Original code will commit previous changes even on failure, this will not. Depends on exactly the behaviour OP wants of course, could go either way.

Comment: @paxdiablo in this case the original code before I added the json failure returns was "$room->save(); $_->save() for @{ $room->members }; $room->ds->commit();" so M42 code was actually okay but thanks a lot for pointing that out. My bad.

Comment: @ado, if this answer meets your needs (and it sounds like it does), you should click on the big green tick mark to accept it. Don't forget to upvote any other useful answers though :-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want logic along these lines:

```
for my $item (@items) {
  $item->stage or die "Some error";
}
$transaction->commit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave the commit until you either fail (if that's what you really want otherwise remove the commented line below) or until all saves are done:

```
if ( $room->save ) {
    for ( @{ $room->members } ) {
    if ( ! $_->save ) {
        $room->ds->commit;                 # possibly remove.
        return $c->render_ng_json("fail");
    }
    $room->ds->commit;
}
```